# Opaqueness of UITextField changes as text entry begins

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I've got a UITextField and its opaqueness changes as soon as the user begins to enter text, see the two screen shots:

[image]
[image]

The view hierarchy is as follows:

Main view (1)
    Scroll View (2)
    Parent container view (3)
        Background UIImage view (4)
        UITextView (5)
        other views

The Parent container view (3) is used to group lots of child views together because they move around the screen as a cohesive unit, its alpha is set to 1 and the background set to clear color. 
Background Image view (4) provides the dark grey portion you can see in the screen shots, its alpha is set to 0.9 so that the Scroll View (2) beneath it is partially visible.

The UITextView (5) has its background color set to whiteColor and its alpha is 1.0.

This is the boarder style used:

[image]

My questions are:
1) Why does the transparency of the UITextView change as soon as the user starts to enter something?
2) How do I make the background of the UITextView to always be non transparent?
3) How do I change the color of the cursor from blue to something else?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: I tried setting up the same arrangement, and mine works just fine.

Comment: Which OS version did you try? This seems to not occur on iOS 7 but does on iOS 6.

Comment: I tried it also on iOS 7.  I can try it on iOS 6 later tonight, if you don't resolve it before then.

Comment: I've got distracted defect fixing so won't be able to pick this up again till after the weekend. Thanks in advance if you are able to try again. P.S. I edited the post to show the boarder style used in case its relevant.